# What is this flowering shrub?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I live in Middle Tennessee and have two of these short shrubs on a side of my house that gets sun for roughly half the day.  I'm curious what they are so that I can look into how to properly care for them.  They grow very slowly, and, if I recall correctly, keep their leaves year-round.

[image]

As you can see, the branches on the one on the right have spread out more fuller, though the one on the left is taller.  Around mid-May, they develop these really nice-looking light-pink (almost peach-colored) flowers.  Here's a close-up of them:

[image]

Can someone properly identify these?  Thank you!

Comment: Have you ptried iNaturalist? I started recently and it's been successful most the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *Rhododendron* - this type was previously known as Azalea, but now they're all called Rhododendron. Azalea types can be deciduous or evergreen, and have smaller leaves than what's always been called Rhododendron.  The flower colour is relatively unusual - it might be *Rhododendron Encore 'Autumn Sunburst* pictured here https://www.gardenia.net/plant/rhododendron-autumn-sunburst, or *Rhododendron Encore 'Autumn Coral'* but there are hundreds of different varieties.

They do not like to dry out at the root, so water well during hot dry spells. They prefer acidic soil, but I imagine that's what they're growing in, since they look reasonably healthy.

Comment: Thanks!  Looking through some more photos, I think you hit the nail on the head with the Autumn Coral variety.

Answer (score 0):

Azaleas, but not a variety I recognize from the Houston area. They like acid soil so the limestone gravel would usually not be used on them.